# Left Shift Logical by sum of two numbers/registers?

Tags: assembly, arm, bit-shift, instruction-set

Is there a way to perform a left shift logical by a sum of two numbers/registers?

I am thinking of something that looks like this, but actually works:

```
mov r4, r1, lsl add, r7, #1
```

Comment: a = b+b in base 2 is the same as a = b<<1.    a = b+b = 2*b = b<<1.  in arm  add r0,r1,r1 for example.  or add r1,r1,r1 if you only want to modify a register and not use others. (flag results may vary from a left shift)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two instructions (to calculate the shift count in a tmp register).

(unless both numbers are constants.  `lsl r4, r1, #1 + #2` can evaluate at assemble time to `lsl r4, r1, #3`.)

Register + immediate or register+register is not encodable in ARM machine code.  There are only a few bits that encode shift mode (left, right logical, right arithmetic, rotate-right.  And immediate or register count) and shift count (register number or the count as an immediate, but not both).

ASM source is just a way to describe machine-code instructions in text.  It's not like C where you can write a more complicated expression and have it compile to multiple instructions.  So the limits exist because of machine-code encoding limitations, not because of asm syntax / language-design choices.

(`ldr r0, =0x12345678` is a pseudo-instruction that does assemble to more than just one instruction, though, or a PC-relative load from a nearby literal pool.  But other than a few pseudo-instructions for constructing larger values that wouldn't fit in a field as part of one 32-bit ARM or 16-bit thumb/thumb2 instruction, one asm instruction must assemble to one machine instruction.)

According to https://www.scss.tcd.ie/John.Waldron/3d1/barrelshift.pdf, the shift count can *either* be a 5-bit immediate, or the specified as the bottom byte of a register.  Definitely not both.

---

I don't think there are any completely-different instructions you could use instead.  e.g. you can only shift one operand, so you can't get an extra shift-by-one by left-shifting both inputs to `add` by the same amount.

---

**You might be able to optimize away the extra immediate shift, if the code *using* the result can apply the constant part of the shift later.**

I'm not sure if using the barrel shifter adds any latency on some ARM uarches, but if so it wouldn't be ideal to have lots of instructions in a loop that all do an extra shift, vs. one extra instruction to save a shift result in a register.

And of course if you want to use it with instructions that need to shift their other operand, you need the final value.